# Can only browse to Google cannot access other sites

Tags: windows-7, router, windows-8.1, dns, browsing

This problem happens at a number of locations but not at others.

Example 1.

BT Home Hub 2.0 router, BT ISP, dynamic IP address:
From Win 8.1 and Win 7 laptops, we can browse to Google search page and other Google sites and can obtain a Google search results listing but visits to any of those sites always fail.  Even directly via the address bar.  All other internet traffic appears successful, e.g SMTP, IMAP, ...  Nslookup appears to work as expected.
Same location using android device or iOS laptop, no browsing problems.  If we point the Win 8.1 or 7 laptops at a mobile device wifi hotspot (eg android with cell connection) then no problems.

Example 2

Unknown router, Eclipse ISP, dynamic IP address.  Will add more detail shortly:
Same circumstances, same problem.

Example 3

Thomson TG585 v7 router, Sky ISP, static IP address:
All other devices and activity the same but the problem never occurs.

---

Is there a router or Win 8.1 or 7 configuring setting or a known bug/limitation that could produce these symptoms in these circumstances?

Comment: You need to provide more information. What exactly happens when it fails? What is the error message?

Comment: Of course.  Stupid, sorry.  I will revisit those locations and update the post, asap.